# removing tr from table

Tags: jquery

I am drawing a grid using HTML and each tr element has it's own id.  I want to be able to remove a tr on a button click, but not have to redraw the whole grid to show that the row has been deleted.  I can do this using .hide(), but the problem is that I need to call a function to stripe my rows after, and since the row is still considered there, the striping doesn't work properly.  Can anybody suggest a solution?

Comment: `$("tr_selector").remove()` BTW, I am no expert. : )

Comment: Yes, but problem is there's not callback function in remove().

Comment: Why not shift the row to the bottom of the table after you hide it? And if keeping the position is critical, just store it's index in a meta value, or make note of the previous row's id (if present) so you can then re-add it after. (Or change your striping selector to exclude those that are hidden, maybe the use of [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)?

Comment: Why not just re-call the function to 'stripe' after calling remove()?  From what I recall, it's synchronous, so you shouldn't need a callback.

Comment: I am calling the stripe function after remove(), but it doesn't seem to be working as it should

Comment: Any chance you could post the striping function?  sounds like there could be an issue there.  None of the solutions posted here actually implement an asynchronous callback, so none of them are likely to help even if the synchronicity is the problem, which I doubt it is.

Comment: Here's a sample of what I was talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/beL4Z/ (note the use of `:visible` in the tr selector)

Answer (score 1):

If you need a call back then write a function that does the remove and then provides a callback function.

```
function remove(element, callback)
{
    $(element).remove();

    if ( typeof callback !== 'undefined' ) callback();
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
remove('#myId', function() {

    // Do stuff.

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just:

```
$('tr_selector').remove();
if (!$('tr_selector')) {
   //doesn't exist - do stuff
}
```

**Ignore my answer - Seth's is better...**